# How to display SVG in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

There are any way to display dynamically loaded SVG in FLEX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no "native" way to load and display SVG files dynamically.

From the latest [flex documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f9d.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63b33-7fba):

> **SVG drawing restrictions**
>
> - **You can only embed an SVG file in an application; you cannot load one at run time**
> - SMIL and animation are not supported
> - Masking and filters are not supported
> - Pattern Fill and some advanced Gradients are not supported
> - Interactivity and scripting is not supported
> - SVG text is rendered as nonsearchable and nonselectable SWF shape outlines, meaning it is not rendered as native text in Flash Player or AIR

Alternatively you can use third-party libs to do the work, such as:

- http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/
- http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/

Comment: Thanks for complete answer, it is very useful for me :)

Answer (score 2):

did you try [`spark.primitives.Path`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Path.html)?